# sed - Delete lines only if they contain multiple instances of a string

Tags: string, awk, sed, duplicates

I have a text file that contains numerous lines that have partially duplicated strings.  I would like to remove lines where a string match occurs twice, such that I am left only with lines with a single match (or no match at all).

An example output:

```
g1: sample1_out|g2039.t1.faa sample1_out|g334.t1.faa sample1_out|g5678.t1.faa sample2_out|g361.t1.faa sample3_out|g1380.t1.faa sample4_out|g597.t1.faa
g2: sample1_out|g2134.t1.faa sample2_out|g1940.t1.faa sample2_out|g45.t1.faa sample4_out|g1246.t1.faa sample3_out|g2594.t1.faa
g3: sample1_out|g2198.t1.faa sample5_out|g1035.t1.faa sample3_out|g1504.t1.faa sample5_out|g441.t1.faa
g4: sample1_out|g2357.t1.faa sample2_out|g686.t1.faa sample3_out|g1251.t1.faa sample4_out|g2021.t1.faa
```

In this case I would like to remove lines 1, 2, and 3 because sample1 is repeated multiple times on line 1, sample 2 is twice on line 2, and sample 5 is repeated twice on line 3.  Line 4 would pass because it contains only one instance of each sample.

I am okay repeating this operation multiple times using different 'match' strings (e.g. sample1_out , sample2_out etc in the example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one in GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F"[| ]" '{         # pipe or space is the field reparator
    delete a              # delete previous hash
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)   # iterate every other field, ie right side of space
        if($i in a)       # if it has been seen already
            next          # skit this record
        else              # well, else
            a[$i]         # hash this entry
    print                 # output if you make it this far
}' file
```

Output:

```
g4: sample1_out|g2357.t1.faa sample2_out|g686.t1.faa sample3_out|g1251.t1.faa sample4_out|g2021.t1.faa
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` command will accomplish what you want.

```
sed -ne '/.* \(.*\)|.*\1.*/!p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

grep: `grep -vE '(sample[0-9]).*\1' file`

Answer (score 0):

Inspiring from Glenn's answer:  use `-i` with sed to directly do changes in the file.

```
sed -r '/(sample[0-9]).*\1/d' txt_file
```